# New to Python. Need info on the environment for it

Tags: python, ide

I'm a complete newbie to Python. I've worked on PHP/JavaScript earlier but starting today I'm moving onto Python. I have no idea about the environment needed for it. I could use some suggestions on it for me to get started.

Comment: Your question could be more precise: are you looking for an Integrated Development Environment?  If yes, what platform do you intend to use?

Answer (score 3):

Under Unix, Emacs is a good choice, to which I always come back, because it is convenient to have a single editor for everything, and because it's open source.

What is best for you depends on your past experience with IDEs.  I'd say: stick with what you've been using, or take this opportunity to try an even better IDE.

Note: Python comes with Idle, which is a very simple (if limited) IDE.

Comment: Why limit it to "Under Unix"?

Answer (score 2):

Be sure to check out IPython. It's an enhanced interactive python shell with a bunch of useful features such as Tab-Completion using introspection (eg, type "my_object." to see a list of its attributes and methods), logging your interactive session to an executable python-file, defining macros, etc. The [documentation page](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/Documentation) has a link to the tutorial as well as screencasts showing it in action.

Answer (score 1):

On my mac/Linux machines, python came pre-installed. On windows I use both [jython](http://jython.org) under the [eclipse](http://eclipse.org) IDE and [ActivePython](http://ActiveState.com/activepython) with their IDE/eclipse.   With [eclipse](http://eclipse.org) you'll want [PyDev](http://pydev.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on what you are looking for and what you are already using.

For instance, if you are using a more 'simple' editor at the moment: as long as it's got Python syntax you've got the basics.

If you are used to e.g. [Eclipse](http://eclipse.org/) you can just continue to use that, combined with [Pydev](http://pydev.sourceforge.net). Besides syntax highlighting you'll also get more fancy features to help you debug and [refactor](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Code_refactoring) your code.

Personally I use [Emacs](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/) with [python-mode](https://launchpad.net/python-mode) (and a few other modes to interface with Subversion and Git). In the past I used [Vim](http://www.vim.org/) which also worked quite well.

My advice would be to start out with your current environment as long as it has some rudimentary support for Python. Once you are familiar with the language, start exploring what your environment is missing and either add it or if you cannot, switch to an enviroment which does support the feature.

Answer (score 1):

I use gvim with some plugin in order to have better support for python.

If you like IDE, look at [wing IDE](http://www.wingware.com/) wich is the best I have tested so far. Especially the debuger included is really helpful.

Comment: Would be nice to know which plugin for gvim.

Comment: sorry for the late response. In case you're still interested, I would say taglist, python.vim, Align, pyflake.
If you want, I can send you my vimfiles.

Answer (score 0):

The [Python Beginner's Guide](http://wiki.python.org/moin/BeginnersGuide) and the official [Python Tutorial](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/) both seem like good places to start.

Answer (score 0):

Geany is a good option for a Linux setup, it's intellisense isn't that great but syntax highlighting is good and it can compile your code directly from inside the editor, plus it handles other languages such as C/C++, PHP, Java etc...  Eric is another popular choice as it's a full IDE and I know some people use Eclipse.

On windows I use Notepad++, but it's mostly because I like text editors instead of fully blown IDE's.

Reference wise Daniel's choices are very good places to start, also check out [Green Tea Press](http://www.greenteapress.com/) who do free computer books, there are two Python choices on there but the "Python for Software Design" book hasn't yet been published properly although you can download the manuscript.  The "How to Think Like a Computer Scientist" book is a good one and not as scary as it sounds.

Answer (score 0):

[IDLE](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IDLE_(Python)) is nice to try out things. Other tools that people like are [Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/) with the [Pydev](http://pydev.sourceforge.net/) plugin which seems to work ok, although it has crashed a few times (Eclipse, that is) and [NetBeans](http://www.netbeans.org/) (which I haven't tried) but some people seem to like.

Answer (score 0):

I can only help you if you're running a Mac. Download [Xcode](http://developer.apple.com/technology/xcode.html). I believe that Python 2.3 comes bundled with these development tools. Luckily enough, this is all you really need to get started, unless you want a newer version of Python.

All you need to do is open up Terminal and type `python`. You're done!